# How to call getSelectedValues on a SELECT with MaterializeCSS

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors, html-select, materialize

The case is simple. I just want to get the selected values of a select Box.
I am using [MaterializeCSS](https://materializecss.com) and JQuery.

Materialize provides a good documentation to its [Select Form Item](https://materializecss.com/select.html).

Here, we can learn, that a Select Box first has to be initialized with a formSelect()-Function.
This is what I do in my JavaScript file:

```
<div id="managementsite">
    <h3 class="center">Management</h3>

    <div class="toolbar">
        <div class="input-field left">
            <select>
                <option value="" disabled selected>Choose Filter</option>
                <option value="a">Define new filter</option>
                <option value="1">Filter1</option>
                <option value="2">Filter2</option>
            </select>
        </div><i class="material-icons left">check</i>
    </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#managementsite select').formSelect();
});
```

So now, the select box is initialized.

I now want to choose an item from it, click on a button and get the value from my chosen item.
Again: the value! Not the inner text.

So, Materialize gives us a method to do this. .getSelectedValues() is the function to call.
But unfortunately, this only gives me an empty string array with length 1.

This is what I do:

```
$("#managementsite .toolbar").on("click", "i.material-icons", function(e){
  var filter = $("#managementsite .toolbar .input-field ul li.selected");

  console.log($('#managementsite .toolbar .input-field ul').formSelect("getSelectedValues"));
  //Then do something with the value
});
```

The reason, why I am *not* refering to the Select Field is, that the origin Select field will be hidden and overridden with something like

```
<div class="select-wrapper">
    <input class="select-dropdown dropdown-trigger" type="text" readonly="true" data-target="select-options-c51fc90b-2c60-e17d-9466-2e2cf7216a96">
    <ul id="select-options-c51fc90b-2c60-e17d-9466-2e2cf7216a96" class="dropdown-content select-dropdown" tabindex="0">
        <li class="disabled selected" id="select-options-c51fc90b-2c60-e17d-9466-2e2cf7216a960" tabindex="0"><span>Choose Filter</span></li>
        <li id="select-options-c51fc90b-2c60-e17d-9466-2e2cf7216a961" tabindex="0"><span>Define new filter</span></li>
        <li id="select-options-c51fc90b-2c60-e17d-9466-2e2cf7216a962" tabindex="0" class="selected"><span>Filter1</span></li>
        <li id="select-options-c51fc90b-2c60-e17d-9466-2e2cf7216a963" tabindex="0"><span>Filter2</span></li>
    </ul>
    <svg class="caret" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M7 10l5 5 5-5z"></path><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path></svg>
    <select tabindex="-1">
        <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Choose Filter</option>
        <option value="a">Define new filter</option>
        <option value="1">Sev4,5+PROD</option>
        <option value="2">Only Java</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

So the question is, how to call the getSelectedValues() Method correctly. On which object do I call the method?
As you can see above, the `<select>-<option>` does not change when I choose an option. But the `<ul>-<li>` does, since there is `class="selected"` in the `<li>` when I choose it.

That means, I can filter the selected `<li>`, but then I cannot get the value from the `<option>` tags.

The reason for wanting the values is, that I want to differ between "I choose a Filter" and "I want to define a new filter" which is value "a". When value a is selected, I want to display a modal, where the user can define his new filter.

When choosing the other values, the filter has to be called from the Database and applied.

Hope you understand my question.
Please help me, how can I get the selected Value(!) from the Select Box / `<ul>`-List correctly?

Greetings, xola

Answer (score 1):

call

```
$('#managementsite select').formSelect();
```

on click method before getSelectedValues
then

```
M.FormSelect.getInstance(select_filter).getSelectedValues()[0]
```

will give you the selected value

also give an id for select as "select_filter"